# Get javacomponent handle in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to create a  GUI in matlab that has a ColorPicker ,an axis to display the chosen color and a button to display it.
till now I created the ColorPicker using javacomponent as follows in the opening function callback:

```
 pp1 = com.mathworks.mlwidgets.graphics.ColorPicker(0,0,'');
 [j,c]=javacomponent(pp1,[450,315,30,20],gcf);
```

Now what I need to do in buttonDownFcn callback is to get the chosen color: my problem is i can't access the ColorPicker since it is not a uicontrol I mean when I type: `myhandle = guihandles(hObject)` I can't see the colorpicker handle .

How do I get the handle for a javacomponent in matlab?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You either save it in your handles structure when you create it. That way you have access to it in any of your callbacks or you can use [findjobj](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects) to find it in your callback.